# how to make correct json data in order to do streaming insert to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been trying streaming insert to Google BigQuery but I got error about json format. However, I have no idea how to change my code . Anyone help me  ??
Thank you so much .

```
main.py

import json
import csv
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = 'galvanic-ripsaw-xxxxx'
table_name = "test"
dataset_name = 'test_dataset'
full_table_name = dataset_name + '.' + table_name
client = bigquery.Client()

result = []
with open('./test.csv','r') as f:
    for line in csv.DictReader(f):
        line_json = json.dumps(line)
        result.append(line_json)
#print(result)

errors = client.insert_rows_json(
    full_table_name,result
)

if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

```
Error message 

Invalid value at 'rows[1].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), "{"pgid": "k1efbnb4ju-300r-9gto-i4z7-0r1j273403668", "last_login_date": "2020-12-01", "start_chat_numbers": "14", "username": "Kento(\u00e7\u0094\u00b0\u00e6\u009d\u0091\u00e5\u0081\u00a5\u00e4\u00ba\u00ba)", "luid": "U6e58c683", "Q1_start": "1", "Q1_start_date": "2020-12-01", "Q2_start": "1", "Q2_start_date": "2020-12-01", "Q3_start": "1", "Q3_start_date": "2020-12-01", "Q4_start": "1", "Q4_start_date": "2020-12-01", "Q5_start": "1", "Q5_start_date": "2020-12-01", "first_purchased": ""}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `line_json = json.dumps(line)` returns "class string". Use `line_json = dict(line)` instead as this returns a "class dict". You can then satisfy the required parameters for insert_rows_json method

[insert_rows_json](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows_json) accepts the following parameters:

> insert_rows_json(table, json_rows, row_ids=None,
> skip_invalid_rows=None, ignore_unknown_values=None,
> template_suffix=None, retry=<google.api_core.retry.Retry object>,
> timeout=None)[source]

json_rows requires a dictionary

> json_rows (Sequence[Dict]) – Row data to be inserted. Keys must match
> the table schema fields and values must be JSON-compatible
> representations.